# How to Convert SQL query into spark DataFrame selectExpr format to build query

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I would like to build similar below query into databricks dataframe using selectExpr to build querys. we have to build similar query to using selecExpr API to build new dataframe.

```
SELECT 
       ,a.column1
       ,b.ccname AS columnname
       ,c.aname AS addcolumn1
       ,c.aaname AS addcolumn2
       ,c.tname AS columnc
       ,c.ssname AS columns
       ,c.ccname AS columncc
FROM (
      SELECT ss.*
            ,Ph.testcol AS column1
      FROM table1 as ss
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT ppcolumn1, MAX(ppcolumn1) AS max_ppcolumn1
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY ppcolumn1
      ) AS mm
      ON ss.ppcolumn1 = mm.ppcolumn1
      AND ss.ppcolumn1 = mm.max_ppcolumn1
      INNER JOIN table3 as Ph
        on ss.columnid = Ph.columnid
      ) AS a

  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT ssco.*
      FROM table3 AS ssco
      INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT cscol AS cscol, MAX(csacol1) AS max_csacol
      FROM table3
      GROUP BY cscol
      ) AS mmsq
      ON ssco.cscol = mmsq.cscol
      AND ssco.csacol1 = mmsq.csacol1
    ) AS b
  ON a.colid = b.cscol
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  
    (
      SELECT ssad.*
      FROM table4 AS ssad
      INNER JOIN
      (
      SELECT adcol AS adcol, MAX(colsq) AS max_colsq
      FROM table4
      GROUP BY adcol
      ) AS mmsq
      ON ssad.adcol = mmsq.adcol
      AND ssad.colsq = mmsq.max_colsq
    ) AS c
  ON a.colid = c.adcol
```

expecting as below format of pyspark API to use build the query for my requirement, kindly assist.

```
df.selectExpr('col1',col2 ..etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

- To convert the given SQL query into the `selectExpr` format, we can break down the query into its small parts and convert each part into the `selectExpr` format.
- Subqueries can be converted into separate DataFrames and join them using the join method. We can also use the `selectExpr` method to select specific columns from each DataFrame and apply transformations to them.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max

a = (
    table1.alias("ss")
    .join(
        table2.groupBy("ppcolumn1")
        .agg(max("ppcolumn1").alias("max_ppcolumn1"))
        .alias("mm"),
        (col("ss.ppcolumn1") == col("mm.ppcolumn1"))
        & (col("ss.ppcolumn1") == col("mm.max_ppcolumn1")),
    )
    .join(table3.alias("Ph"), col("ss.columnid") == col("Ph.columnid"))
    .select(col("ss.*"), col("Ph.testcol").alias("column1"))
    .alias("a")
)

b = (
    table3.alias("ssco")
    .join(
        table3.groupBy("cscol")
        .agg(max("csacol1").alias("max_csacol"))
        .alias("mmsq"),
        (col("ssco.cscol") == col("mmsq.cscol"))
        & (col("ssco.csacol1") == col("mmsq.max_csacol")),
    )
    .select(col("ssco.*"), col("ccname").alias("columnname"))
    .alias("b")
)

c = (
    table4.alias("ssad")
    .join(
        table4.groupBy("adcol")
        .agg(max("colsq").alias("max_colsq"))
        .alias("mmsq"),
        (col("ssad.adcol") == col("mmsq.adcol"))
        & (col("ssad.colsq") == col("mmsq.max_colsq")),
    )
    .select(
        col("ssad.*"),
        col("aname").alias("addcolumn1"),
        col("aaname").alias("addcolumn2"),
        col("tname").alias("columnc"),
        col("ssname").alias("columns"),
        col("ccname").alias("columncc"),
    )
    .alias("c")
    result = (
    a.join(b, col("a.colid") == col("b.cscol"), "left_outer")
    .join(c, col("a.colid") == col("c.adcol"), "left_outer")
    .select(
        col("a.column1"),
        col("b.columnname"),
        col("c.addcolumn1"),
        col("c.addcolumn2"),
        col("c.columnc"),
        col("c.columns"),
        col("c.columncc"),
    )
)
```

In this code, `table1`, `table2`,`table3`,`table4` are dataframes. In order to convert the spark sql tables to dataframes,  the below code is used.

`table1= sqlContext.sql('select  *  from table1')`

After converting to dataframes, above code is used.

Comment: third one c section query facing some issues

Comment: if possible, we chat in this stack overfow

Comment: Join [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255203/77056387)